# Efficient way to turn a matrix into a triplet (i,j,v)

Tags: r

#### The What

Given some `matrix`:

```
mat <- matrix(1:10,ncol=2)
```

I want to transform it to the following triplet format: (i,j,v) where `i` is the row index, `j` is the column index and `v` is the value at i,j (you can see **why** at the bottom)

What I have tried:

```
  matrixToTriplet <- function(mat) {
    i <- 1:nrow(mat)
    nj <- ncol(mat)
    j <- 1:nj
    output <- matrix(numeric(0), ncol=3)
    for(i_ in i) {
      curr <- c(rep(i_, times=nj),j,mat[i_,])
      output <- rbind(output, matrix(curr, ncol=3))
    }
    output
  }
```

The output should be:

```
> matrixToTriplet(mat)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    2    6
 [3,]    2    1    2
 [4,]    2    2    7
 [5,]    3    1    3
 [6,]    3    2    8
 [7,]    4    1    4
 [8,]    4    2    9
 [9,]    5    1    5
[10,]    5    2   10
```

I also had another version using `apply` and `sapply` instead of `for` but those would explode very quickly. The kind of sizes I am working on is quite large, 1600x1600 matrices.

#### The Why

One might ask "why"?, the reason for this is that I need the `i`s and `j`s as features for a model to predict `v`. If there is a better way to do this I am interested to hear.

Comment: Any reason why you haven't accepted any of the 9 questions you have posted until now?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use `which` argument with `arr.ind= TRUE` parameter which exactly does what you want however, the issue is it expects a logical value. So we need to find a condition in which all the values turn out to be `TRUE`. In this case I see all values are greater than 0. So we can do

```
#as.vector suggested by @snoram and verified by @mt1022 that it is faster
cbind(which(mat > 0, arr.ind = TRUE), val = as.vector(mat))


#      row col val
# [1,]   1   1   1
# [2,]   2   1   2
# [3,]   3   1   3
# [4,]   4   1   4
# [5,]   5   1   5
# [6,]   1   2   6
# [7,]   2   2   7
# [8,]   3   2   8
# [9,]   4   2   9
#[10,]   5   2  10
```

---

If you are not able to find any such condition which would make all the values to be `TRUE` we could just create a new matrix with same dimensions as `mat` with all values as `TRUE` using `relist`

```
cbind(which(relist(TRUE, mat), arr.ind = TRUE), value = as.vector(mat))


#      row col value
# [1,]   1   1     1
# [2,]   2   1     2
# [3,]   3   1     3
# [4,]   4   1     4
# [5,]   5   1     5
# [6,]   1   2     6
# [7,]   2   2     7
# [8,]   3   2     8
# [9,]   4   2     9
#[10,]   5   2    10
```

Comment: Great. but I would do `as.vector(mat)` instead of `c(mat)`.

Comment: I agree with @snoram. Actually I did another benchmark with `as.vector` for solutions using `c()`. It turns out that `as.vector(mat)` is faster than `c(mat)`.

Comment: @mt1022 interesting!, My reasoning has to do with readability.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `row` and `col`:

```
x <- t(mat)
cbind(c(col(x)), c(row(x)), c(x))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    2    6
# [3,]    2    1    2
# [4,]    2    2    7
# [5,]    3    1    3
# [6,]    3    2    8
# [7,]    4    1    4
# [8,]    4    2    9
# [9,]    5    1    5
# [10,]    5    2   10
```

If the row order does not matter in the final output, we can also do it with `cbind(c(row(mat)), c(col(mat)), c(mat))` directly.

A benchmark will be helpful when talking about efficiency:

```
library(microbenchmark)
bmf <- function(mat, ...){
    microbenchmark(
        a = {x <- t(mat);cbind(c(col(x)), c(row(x)), c(x))},
        a2 = {cbind(c(row(mat)), c(col(mat)), c(mat))},
        b = {cbind(which(mat > 0, arr.ind = TRUE), val = c(mat))},
        c = {cbind(expand.grid(seq(nrow(mat)), seq(ncol(mat))), as.vector(mat))},
        ...)
}

mat <- matrix(seq_len(10*10), 10, 10)
bmf(mat, times = 10)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
#     a   7.985   9.239  18.2556  15.0415  22.756  47.065    10
#    a2   4.310   4.681   5.5257   5.2405   5.755   9.099    10
#     b  17.032  21.672  35.8950  28.7505  59.170  68.436    10
#     c 216.101 228.736 267.7217 243.9465 288.455 380.096    10'


mat <- matrix(seq_len(1000*1000), 1000, 1000)
bmf(mat, times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
#     a 17.70805 20.51167 36.73432 21.79357  24.56775 111.6796    10
#    a2 14.61793 20.95486 37.70526 25.58968 30.91322  98.44344    10
#     b 41.74630 45.49698 76.61307 47.86678 122.90142 178.8363    10
#     c 14.40912 17.84025 25.39672 19.29968  20.12222  85.2515    10
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who really like `expand.grid`:

```
cbind(expand.grid(seq(nrow(mat)), seq(ncol(mat))), as.vector(mat))
```

Comment: Ha!  I actually like @mt1022's `row`/`col` approach better, although I'm not sure why the transpose is necessary.

Comment: See the benchmark in my edit. You answer is still very efficient for large matrix.

Comment: I checked all answers so far on 10K^2 matrices. @DanY is the fastest

Comment: This is a big win for me, I would not have bet on myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is an option using the Matrix package.

```
mat <- matrix(1:10,ncol=2)

#create sparse matrix
library(Matrix)
M <- Matrix(mat, sparse = TRUE)

#turn into triplet representation
M <- as(M, "TsparseMatrix")

#indices are zero-based within Matrix package
m <- cbind(M@i + 1, M@j + 1, M@x) #do you really need a matrix as output?
m[order(m[,1]),] #probably you don't need this step

    #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
    # [1,]    1    1    1
    # [2,]    1    2    6
    # [3,]    2    1    2
    # [4,]    2    2    7
    # [5,]    3    1    3
    # [6,]    3    2    8
    # [7,]    4    1    4
    # [8,]    4    2    9
    # [9,]    5    1    5
    #[10,]    5    2   10
```