How to convert a graph into a sparse adjacency matrix having a given type (other then "dgCMatrix")
How to convert a graph to a sparse ‘dgTmatrix’ in one step?
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)
g <- make_ring(5)
adj <- as_adjacency_matrix(g, sparse = TRUE)
class(adj)
# [1] "dgCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"

How to specify a matrix class other then "dgCMatrix", which seem to be the default?
adt <- as(adj, "TsparseMatrix")
class(adt)
# [1] "dgTMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"
cbind(adt@i, adt@j, adt@x)

I tried: class(as_adj(g, type="both", igraph_opt("dgTMatrix"))) but this creates a "dgCMatrix".
Update
If really needed then making a private copy of get.adjacency.sparse() would be an option.

igraph::as_adjacency_matrix(sparse = TRUE) is always a CsparseMatrix.  It calls Matrix::sparseMatrix without specifying repr = *, and the default value is "C".

The longer (or hopefully not so long) term plan is to make use of the conversion functions from the C core, which create a CSC format. The triplet format is not really useful for anything else than efficient element insertion. Once you're done inserting elements, you convert to CSC or CSR, which make it possible to efficiently multiply matrices. So, in short, it is not planned to provide a direct translation to triplet format. I am curious to know what application you have in mind for the triplet format.

A sparse matrix idx, type "T", could be faster while indexing as in mat[idx]. See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78772639/adding-edge-weights-to-igraph-from-an-adjac

I think it is hard-coded in its source code, you may not be able to annotate it from the inside
get.adjacency.sparse <- function(graph, type = c("both", "upper", "lower"),
                                 attr = NULL, edges = FALSE, names = TRUE) {
  ensure_igraph(graph)

  type <- igraph.match.arg(type)

  vc <- vcount(graph)

  el <- as_edgelist(graph, names = FALSE)
  use.last.ij <- FALSE

  if (edges) {
    value <- seq_len(nrow(el))
    use.last.ij <- TRUE
  } else if (!is.null(attr)) {
    attr <- as.character(attr)
    if (!attr %in% edge_attr_names(graph)) {
      stop("no such edge attribute")
    }
    value <- edge_attr(graph, name = attr)
    if (!is.numeric(value) && !is.logical(value)) {
      stop(
        "Sparse matrices must be either numeric or logical,",
        "and the edge attribute is not"
      )
    }
  } else {
    value <- rep(1, nrow(el))
  }

  if (is_directed(graph)) {
    res <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(dims = c(vc, vc), i = el[, 1], j = el[, 2], x = value, use.last.ij = use.last.ij)
  } else {
    if (type == "upper") {
      ## upper
      res <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(
        dims = c(vc, vc), i = pmin(el[, 1], el[, 2]),
        j = pmax(el[, 1], el[, 2]), x = value, use.last.ij = use.last.ij
      )
    } else if (type == "lower") {
      ## lower
      res <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(
        dims = c(vc, vc), i = pmax(el[, 1], el[, 2]),
        j = pmin(el[, 1], el[, 2]), x = value, use.last.ij = use.last.ij
      )
    } else if (type == "both") {
      ## both
      res <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(
        dims = c(vc, vc), i = pmin(el[, 1], el[, 2]),
        j = pmax(el[, 1], el[, 2]), x = value, symmetric = TRUE, use.last.ij = use.last.ij
      )
      res <- as(res, "generalMatrix")
    }
  }

  if (names && "name" %in% vertex_attr_names(graph)) {
    colnames(res) <- rownames(res) <- V(graph)$name
  }

  res
}

